# Accented letters messed up in PDF readers navigator with LuaLaTeX

Tags: hyperref, luatex, unicode

I have something like this:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\begin{document}
   \section{é}
   \begin{frame}
      test
   \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Problem is that the section name is messed up into the navigation bar of any PDF reader I tried (Okular on Linux, Acrobat Reader on Win, etc.). On the other hand the section name is printed correctly into the PDF itself (i.e. into the .
table of contents, etc.)
[image]

Is there something I can do (in LaTeX) to fix this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Add `\hypersetup{pdfencoding=auto}` to your preamble.

Comment: The shortest question and answer I’ve found on the web which instantaneously solves a problem which has annoyed me for years ! Thanks a lot !